# Magento1: I need to get multiselect dropdown values in grid listing in custom module

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to get multiselect dropdown values in grid listing in custom module.

Please suggest for this.

[image]

Code
form.php

```
$topics = Mage::getModel('abc/category')->getCollection();
        $topics->setOrder('name', 'ASC');
        $topicsArray = array();
        foreach ($topics as $topic) {
            $topicsArray[] = array(
                'label' => $topic->getData('name'),
                'value' => $topic->getData('category_id')
            );
        }
        $selectedTopicsArray = array();
        if($model->getId()) {
            $selectedTopics = Mage::getModel('abc/event_topic_link')->getCollection();
            $selectedTopics->addFieldToFilter('event_id', $model->getId());
            foreach ($selectedTopics as $topic) {
                $selectedTopicsArray[] = $topic->getData('topic_id');
            }
        }
        $infoFieldset->addField('topics', 'multiselect', array(
            'name'      => 'topics',
            'label'     => Mage::helper('abc')->__('Topics'),
            'title'     => Mage::helper('abc')->__('Topics'),
            'required'  => false,
            'onclick'   => 'return false;',
            'onchange'  => 'return false;',
            'value'     => $selectedTopicsArray,
            'values'    => $topicsArray
        ));
```

Comment: Can you please tell me format of value which you saved value in DB?

Comment: I have updated the code in question

Comment: It's M1 code and you asked for M2.

Comment: Extremely sorry this is M1

Comment: How to show in grip.php with selected values

Comment: If you created grid.php then, can you please upload code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102061/discussion-between-rohan-hapani-and-shiwani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this below code in your render function :

```
public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
   $value = $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex());
   $multiselect_arr = explode(',', $value);
   $text_value = array();
   foreach ($multiselect_arr as $item) {
     array_push($text_value, 'load text value');
   }
   $name=implode(', ',$text_value);
   return $name;
}
```